GPS: "...to provide the same accuracy to civilians that was afforded to the military."
Global Positioning System in Wikipedia states:

This changed on May 1, 2000, with U.S. President Bill Clinton signing a policy directive to turn off Selective Availability to provide the same accuracy to civilians that was afforded to the military.

Isn't that statement wrong?
As far as I know there are two different signals:
One for civilians (C/A code), and one for military (P code) with higher accuracy.
In addition the SA (selective availability) added a random kind of positioning error to the civil signal, and only the latter was stopped.
I thought the civil accuracy with SA was like 50 meters, while without SA it is like 10 (16?) meters, and the military accuracy was rumored to be about 2 (6?) meters.
Is that right?

iirc the president's statement is oversimplified and your recollection (10-20m using civilian, 2-6m using P(Y)) is correct. In this case I don't think wikipedia is "wrong" but rather that the lawmakers fiddled with the marketing to make it easier for the public to understand.

Civilian can be a lot better than that, provided you have a good open sky. There was an FAA document from a few years ago that indicates single-frequency aviation GPS getting an error of better than 2 meters more than 95% of the time. A smartphone might be limited to 5-10 m, though, and it degrades if you have obstructions nearby where there's signal blocking and reflection going on.  As I understand it, dual-frequency mode doesn't increase the accuracy under good conditions, but allows better filtering of bad data.

I think the point is the "worst accuracy" that is guaranteed. When I was in the south east of Europe some months ago, I was surprised to see that I was in a different country suddenly. At that time I believed in a bug of my mobile phone, but as the position was suddenly the airport of Beirut (where I definitely was NOT staying, not even 100km nearby), I think some nation tested a GPS jammer before...you know the story...
